# Spark- Saving JavaRDD to Cassandra

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, rdd, spark-cassandra-connector

This [link](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/accessing-cassandra-from-spark-in-java) shows a way to save a `JavaRDD` to `Cassandra` in this way:

```
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraJavaUtil.*;

JavaRDD<Product> productsRDD = sc.parallelize(products);
javaFunctions(productsRDD, Product.class).saveToCassandra("java_api", "products");
```

But the `com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraJavaUtil.*` seems deprecated. The updated API should be:

```
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.*;
```

Can someone show me some codes to store a `JavaRDD` to `Cassandra` using the updated API above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the [documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/7_java_api.md), should be like this:

```
javaFunctions(rdd).writerBuilder("ks", "people", mapToRow(Person.class)).saveToCassandra();
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
JavaRDD<Product> productsRDD = sc.parallelize(products);
javaFunctions(productsRDD, Product.class).saveToCassandra("java_api", "products »);
```

by

```
JavaRDD<Product> productsRDD = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("java_api", "products", mapRowTo(Product.class));
```