# Error in accessing cassandra from spark in java: Unable to import CassandraJavaUtil

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, datastax

I am using the below blog in configuring to access Cassandra from apache spark.

"http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/accessing-cassandra-from-spark-in-java"
"https://gist.github.com/jacek-lewandowski/278bfc936ca990bee35a#file-javademo-java-L177"

However, I am not able to import the CassandraJavaUtil class dependency and my eclipse is displaying an error "The Import cannot be resolved."

```
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraJavaUtil.*;
```

Please help me in resolving this error.

Many thanks.

Comment: See this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323426/spark-saving-javardd-to-cassandra

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also followed the example in the first document that you linked.  You'll notice that in the "Prerequisites" section, step #2 requires you to create the example as a Maven project.  Step #3 lists four dependencies that you need to add to your project.  Two of those dependencies are specific to the Spark Connector:

- com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.10:1.0.0-rc4
- com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10:1.0.0-rc4

Basically, the "dependencies" section of the `pom.xml` for my Spark projects looks like this:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0-alpha2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0-alpha2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Double-check that your `pom.xml` has those dependencies, and then invoke Maven to bring the Spark Connector libraries down locally.  This worked for me:

```
cd workspace/sparkTest2
mvn package
```

Comment: still not working, any pointers? The method javaFunctions(SparkContext) in the type CassandraJavaUtil is not applicable for the 
 arguments (JavaRDD<JavaDemo.Product>, Class<JavaDemo.Product>)

Comment: Have added <!-- Cassandra Spark Connector dependency -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.0</version>
  </dependency>
<!-- Cassandra java Connector dependency -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.0</version>
  </dependency>  still not working any pointers please

Comment: @mithra Go ahead and ask this as a separate question.  That way you will attract more people to look at it.

Answer (score 4):

The class `CassandraJavaUtil` has now been moved to the `japi` package in `com.datastax.spark.connector`

So, try using:-

```
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.*;
```

**Note:**
As per this doc :

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/7_java_api.md

> Since version 1.1.x, Java API comes with several useful factory methods which can be used to create factories of row readers of the two major kinds: type converter based and column mapper based.

Also note that the syntax to use `CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions()`  has also changed. Go through the above reference carefully.